# SOAP web service not recognizing ArrayOfAnyType from PHP client for Agemni Database API

Tags: php, .net, soap

I am trying to insert a lead into the SOAP web service with this WSDL: http://www.agemni.com/AgemniWebservices/service1.asmx?WSDL

The API is documented here: http://wiki.agemni.com/4Integration_And_API%27s/APIs/Database_API

This web service's back end code seems to be in .NET.

Here is my code:

```
// Create soap client.
try {
    $this->client = new SoapClient("https://www.agemni.com/AgemniWebservices/service1.asmx?WSDL", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'cache_wsdl' => 0, "trace" => true));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->logMessage('Couldn\'t connect to web service.');
    throw $e;
}

// Create parameters.
$dataParams = new \stdClass;
$dataParams->strUsername = 'userman';
$dataParams->strPassword = 'hissecretpassword';
$dataParams->strCompanyName = 'validcompanyname';
$leadCode = 2;
$dataParams->objecttype = $leadCode;

// Create keys.
$dataParams->keys = new \stdClass;
$dataParams->keys->Phone = 'Phone';

// Create values.
$dataParams->values = new \stdClass;
$dataParams->values->Phone = '8011234567';

// Call web service.
$validateResult = $this->client->CreateEntity($dataParams);
```

Here is the response I receive:

```
object(stdClass)#27 (1) {
  ["ValidateEntityResult"]=>
  object(SoapVar)#29 (4) {
    ["enc_type"]=>
    int(0)
    ["enc_value"]=>
    object(stdClass)#28 (10) {
      ["statusCode"]=>
      string(9) "Succeeded"
      ["status"]=>
      string(5) "Error"
      ["description"]=>
      string(56) "Phone number is required and needs to be 10 digits long."
      ["errorNumber"]=>
      int(1)
      ["xmlResult"]=>
      string(39) "<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>"
      ["EntityValidated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["EntityCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["EntityUpdated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["EntityIDCreated"]=>
      int(0)
      ["isloggedIn"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["enc_stype"]=>
    string(15) "ExceptionReport"
    ["enc_ns"]=>
    string(44) "http://tempuri.org/AgemniWebService/Service1"
  }
}
```

I found a similar issue on PHPFreaks that was years old and was never successfully answered.  I see other similar issues with nesting parameters in the PHP SoapClient, but all of the suggestions I've seen end in the same error message for me.

The authentication is being received just fine, along with the company name.  However, I've stabbed at formatting, parsing, and encoding the keys and values parameters in nearly every way I could conceive.  I've played with declaring my parameters as SoapVar and SoapParam with every potential constructor parameter I could think of and still have received the same error message.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions as to any reason that someone could suppose that the Agemni web service is not accepting my lead's phone number.

Thanks.

*Update*
I can just generate the XML request I need in a string and send it using cURL, but I'd like to use SoapClient.  However, I have a hard time generating the elements within the keys and values nodes to look like this:

```
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">phone</anyType>'
```

I followed some guides on creating custom complex types in SoapClient, but I couldn't get it to create XML that looks like that.